# How to get value using row and column search

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

I made a budget spreadsheet I'd like to use and have plugged in some numbers to ensure I'm doing everything correctly. I have two sheets: 1. for the budget i.e. I'd like to spend max $1000 for rent and then 2.to track how much I've spent (using data from a data tracking sheet - not important here).

I would like for my tracking sheet to show the budget next to it so I can see how much I have left but I will need to use a look up function to see how much my budget is for all categories within a certain month as I'd like for it to be dynamic and I'm sure it can be done. I've tried using index match with no luck.

Please see my sheets below. As you can see the budget is working fine but only for January, I'd like to switch the month and years to be more dynamic (I'm okay if the selection of these tables have to be pretty manual every year).

I used this index formula:

```
=index(Budget!B8:M24,match(B3,Budget!B7:M7,0))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: How are you currently doing the lookup for January? As an example using table references, you could generate the column name using your date and year selection, like `=INDIRECT("Tracking["&B1&B2&"]")` which becomes `=Tracking[January 2024]`

Comment: Please edit your question to show the index/match formula you are tyring to use and what error(s) you are encountering. IMO, index/match will work, or any other 2-D lookup (nested) formulas.

Comment: Is it related with `Excel` or `Google-Sheets`?

Comment: @Cpt.Whale when I do that I get a #REF error I don't use INDIRECT too often - do you know why that's happening?

Comment: @gns100 updated with my index formula

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Google-Sheets but if this can only happen on excel I'm happy to move it

Comment: I think you could just put `=CONCAT(B1," ", B2)` into B3 or in place of it? Double-check the actual values of your column headers, since Excel likes to convert "January 2024" into other formats. I forgot to include the space in the indirect example, like: `=INDIRECT("Tracking["&B1&" "&B2&"]")`

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a combination of `INDEX()`+`MATCH()`+`MATCH()` or if using `MS365` then using `XLOOKUP()` with `FILTER()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C11</kbd> --> Formula will spill for the whole range.

```
=XLOOKUP(A11:A28,Budget!A8:A24,FILTER(Budget!B8:F24,B3=Budget!B7:F7),0)
```

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C11</kbd> --> Formula needs to fill down!

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Budget!$B$8:$F$24,
 MATCH($A11,Budget!$A$8:$A$24,0),
 MATCH($B$3,Budget!$B$7:$F$7,0)),"")
```

---

The formula in screenshot uses defined names uses respective ranges to denote.

```
=XLOOKUP(ExpTrack,ExpBud,FILTER(Values,Month_and_Year=Months),0)
```

---

Comment: thank you so much for doing all this work for me! I didn't know index match match was an option and it worked for me! I'm also realizing the "Month and year" (B3) cell is concatenating the above rows "Month" (B1) and "Year" (B2) and creates an error for the index match function. I'm going to insert this manually but I'm sure I can look into how to get these to be automatic using the drop downs. Thank you so much this is going to be a huge time saver I appreciate it so much!

Comment: @Nikki If that helps to resolve the query then please click on the tick mark beside the answer so it helps someone in the future.

Comment: @Nikki here is the **[Excel_Workbook](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2cknYRoaPNOG9k2vRc?e=8gzTzw)** feel free to download to see what I have done. So it may help you as well